# Is there any way to change the color of whole website to complementary color?

Tags: css

I want to change the colors of website using CSS, and I wonder know is there any way to change the color of whole website to complementary color?

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the appropriate CSS selector and define the color property with the value you want. For example, say you want to change the color of all paragraphs on your site to navy. Then you'd add p {color: #000080; } to the head section of your HTML file.
and you should change the background color of your website .

refrence:
[1]: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/change-background-color-html